# Am I freeing this linked list in the correct manner?

Tags: c, linked-list, free

Is this the correct way to free a linked list? I have the following structs:

```
struct Courses{
    char *courseName;
    int creditValue;
    Courses *next;
}Courses;

struct Student{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Courses *list;  //First course (node)
}Student;
```

This is my free function:

```
void freeStudent(Student *student){
    struct Courses *tmp = student->list;

    while(tmp != NULL){
        free(tmp->name);
        free(tmp);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Am I ordering my free function wrong? Should I be doing `tmp = tmp->next` before freeing `tmp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is wrong

```
free(tmp);
tmp = tmp->next;
```

After you free `tmp` it becomes a dangling pointer (which is why some people would set it to `NULL`). You shouldn't attempt to access it like this `tmp->next`

I would recommend this version for freeing

```
void freeStudent(Student *student){
    struct Courses *tmp = student->list, *pre;

    while(tmp != NULL){
        free(tmp->name);
        pre = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = pre;
    }
}
```